# What's a (single-sorted) algebraic signature?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I am participating in an undergrad project that uses the book ***Nominal Sets*** by Andrew M. Pitts. I don't fully understand half of the things he attempts to explain but that is another issue, the main issue is that just at the end of Chapter 1.1 there is an example which include algebraic signature that states:

**Example 1.4** Let $\Sigma$ be a (single-sorted) algebraic signature. Thus $\Sigma = (\Sigma_n | n \in \mathbb{N})$ is a countably infinite family of sets. The elements of each set $\Sigma_n$ are the $n$-ary operations of the signature. The set $\Sigma[X]$ of *algebraic terms* over $\Sigma$ with variables drawn from some set $X$ is inductively defined by the following rules:

$$
\frac{x \in X}{x \in \Sigma[X]} \qquad
\frac{t_1 \in \Sigma[X] \quad \cdots \quad t_n \in \Sigma[X] \qquad \text{op} \in \Sigma_n}{\text{op}(t_1, \ldots, t_n) \in \Sigma[X]}.
$$

There is an action of $\text{Sym}_X$ on $\Sigma[X]$ given by applying a permutation to variables where they occur in algebraic terms:

$$
\pi \cdot x = \pi x, \\
\pi \cdot \text{op}(t_1, \ldots, t_n) = \text{op}(\pi \cdot t_1, \ldots, \pi \cdot t_n).
$$

Help me understand this example please.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic)

Comment: Consider the alternative: you are *attempting to understand* what the book explains. But more seriously, it's difficult to explain this without knowing your background (do you know what a ring is, do you know what a free algebra is)? A slower introduction to signatures, terms, and algebras can be found at the begining of [these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.05923).